# VBA how to improve this code and make it more efficient?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code for my vba excel. i am repeating the same code again and again to add my values from sheet2 to sheet1. any help?

```
    For j = 1 To Sheet1LastRow
    For i = 1 To Sheet2LastRow
        If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(j, 7).Value = Worksheets("sheet2 ").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(j , 11).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i ,1 ).Value
            Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(j, 12).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value
            Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(j, 13).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value
            Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(j, 14).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i, 4).Value


        Else
        End If
Next i
Next j
```

Comment: if you copy the complete code and maybe some sample data and what you want to achieve, we could help you more precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contiguous ranges can be copied in one operation:

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet  

Set sht1  = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2  = Worksheets("Sheet2")

For j = 1 To Sheet1LastRow
    For i = 1 To Sheet2LastRow
        If sht1.Cells(j, 7).Value = sht2.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                sht1.Cells(j, 11).Resize(1, 4).Value = _
                              sht2.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value
        End If
    Next i
Next j
```

Comment: thank you for your valuable effort but it did not work :(

Comment: It's the more or less the same as your posted code.  Does *that* not work?  And do you get an error or ?

Comment: Does it ever hit the line which copies the data?  Put a breakpoint on that line and run it.

Comment: hey thank you for your reply it does not hit the line. the loop not even function :/

Comment: If the loops are not even running then you need to check the values of `Sheet1LastRow` are what you expect.  I can't really debug from here.

Comment: the problem is with sht1.Cells(j, 7). if i put the data on A column and put  sht1.Cells (j,1) instead of  sht1.Cells(j, 7) then it works. However i want to do it from sht1.Cells(j, 7). any idea?